# 2018 15" MacBook Pro WiFi throughput issues

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have a 2018, 15" MacBook Pro, running macOS 10.15.7 (the rest of the specs are irrelevant). I have a D-Link DIR-882 WiFi router (which is AC2600 according to the manufacturer; allegedly it can achieve 1733 Mbps over a 5 GHz link).

Test setup: MacBook Pro connected over 5 GHz at a PHY speed of 1,300 Mbps (both checked by Option-clicking the WiFi icon). There is minimal interference on the 5 GHz channel in use: only a single other access point in the same channel, at about -90 dBm. The MacBook Pro is placed about 3 feet away from the router, but tests were also repeated at distances less than 1 feet and about 5 feet, with the same results.

My ISP is 600 Mbps/300 Mbps. I tested this with Ookla Speedtest, and I do achieve the advertised speeds, so long as I do this using Gigabit (wired) Ethernet (using an USB-C to Gigabit Ethernet dongle). Over WiFi, the best downstream speed I can achieve is 500 Mbps; this is with both Chrome and Safari.

I also used [an app](https://www.duckware.com/speedtest/index.html) to test network throughput inside my LAN. The server is running on a PC directly connected to the same router via Gigabit Ethernet. When the MacBook Pro is also connected via Gigabit Ethernet, I can achieve ~940 Mbps throughput. Switching back to WiFi, I achieve up to 730 Mbps.

First, are these speeds reasonable? While I'm aware there's overhead, I'd like to think something closer to 1 Gbps would be achievable over WiFi. I guess 730 Mbps is OK given it's less than my ISP's speed, but 500 Mbps when using Ookla Speedtest means I'm not getting my money's worth from my ISP.

Second, is there anything I can do to improve these figures?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Option-WiFi menu when you're seeing your suboptimal transfer rates? And also a screenshot of the router's Wireless > Advanced settings.

Comment: Yes, they are reasonable.  A bit over half the headline speed (1300) for local file transfer is fine.